# Maintain the table view's scroll position

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode9, swift4

In my app I have a list of foods, that pop up from the side menu like this

[image]

Upon clicking any index it segues to a food screen where it shows respective details. this ham icon launches the side menu. what I want is when the user lets say selects the 28th or 30th index down the list. when he clicks again on the hamIcon he should come back to the same scroll position where he left, currently, it takes the user back to the top, how can I achieve that. I browsed stack and all I could find was obj-c version of the problem. and I don't know obj-c at all. I also came across a third party library but I don't want to do that for such a trivial task. Please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply store the last click index path in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

And simply call scrollToRowAtIndexPath method from viewWillApperar.

```
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: Implementing the above solution in viewWillAppear is purely dependent on the implementation of the side menu. If one simply animates the view in and out, viewWillAppear will not be called always. It will work if you re-initialize the sideMenu view controller everytime the user taps on the hamburger. If you only initialize it once, you should consider applying the above logic at the tap of the hamburger.

Comment: this scrollToRowAtIndexPath will take the stored index right? i can store it as `let cell = tableView.cellForRowAt(indexpath)` but how would i assign it to scrollToRowAtIndexPath cz it wouldn't recognize that cell defined in the didSelectRowAt